# html:radio dynamic values value

Tags: java, struts

I am using Struts 1.2 for my application. I need to iterarte through a List and create `<html:radio>` based on the number of items present in the list. For iterating through the List, I am using `<logic:iterator>`. The list is set as an attribute to the request.

This is the code I am using:

```
<logic:iterate name="mediaTypes" id="type">                             
<html:radio name="rentMediaForm" property="mediaType" value="type"></html:radio>
<bean:write name="type"/>
</logic:iterate>
```

But every time the values of the radio is getting assigned to "type". I want the value to be dynamic based on the iteration value.

I am getting the value properly in the below line:

`<bean:write name="type"/>`

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the EL (expression language) to get the value of `type`, e.g.:

```
<html:radio name="rentMediaForm" property="mediaType" value="${type}"></html:radio>
```

Also note, that your application should be at least of Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0 level in order to be able seamlessly process EL expressions. Otherwise, you might need to switch to [EL-aware version of struts-html tags](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-el/tagreference.html#struts-html-el.tld).